# Filter XML based on attribute value using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have searched here and I'm not able to find how to filter an xml based on their attribute. I have this xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <document>
            <document_head>
                <title>This is the title</title>
                <version>This is the title</version>
            </document_head>
            <document_body>
                <paragraph id="AXD">
                    <text>
                        This is a text that should be in the result
                    </text>
                    <properties>
                        <size>13px</size>
                        <color>#000000</color>
                    </properties>
                    <author>Current user</author>
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph id="SFI">
                    <properties>
                        <text>
                            This is some other text that should not be in there
                        </text>
                    </properties>
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph id="SFA">
                    <author>Some random guy</author>
                </paragraph>      
                <paragraph id="ARG">
                    This doesn't mean anything.
                </paragraph>
                <paragraph id="RRR">
                    This does, hence should be in there.
                </paragraph>
            </document_body>
        </document>
```

I expect this result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
        <document_head>
            <title>This is the title</title>
            <version>This is the title</version>
        </document_head>
        <document_body>
            <paragraph id="AXD">
                <text>
                    This is a text that should be in the result
                </text>
                <properties>
                    <size>13px</size>
                    <color>#000000</color>
                </properties>
                <author>Current user</author>
            </paragraph>
            <paragraph id="RRR">
                This does, hence should be in there.
            </paragraph>      
        </document_body>
    </document>
```

Currently, I have this XSLT:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>  
      <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template match="document_body/paragraph[not(@id='AXD')][not(@id='RRR')]" />
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which produces this XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <document>
            <document_head>
                <title>This is the title</title>
                <version>This is the title</version>
            </document_head>
            <document_body>
                <paragraph id="AXD">
                    <text>
                        This is a text that should be in the result
                    </text>
                    <properties>
                        <size>13px</size>
                        <color>#000000</color>
                    </properties>
                    <author>Current user</author>
                </paragraph>      
            </document_body>
        </document>
```

Do you know what I am missing?

Thanks.

**Update:** It seems that the code works for another XSLT processor, but it doesn't for Java Transformer.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working? I just tried, and it did produce your expected output!

Comment: @tim-c Hi Tim. Yes, I tried it several times using Java, and nothing. It gives me the result that I posted. It seems that it is not checking for the second condition :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sure your condition should work! However, here is couple of alternative ways to check, so give this a go instead to see if that makes a difference.

```
<xsl:template match="document_body/paragraph[not(@id='AXD' or @id='RRR')]"/>

<xsl:template match="document_body/paragraph[@id != 'AXD' and @id != 'RRR']"/>
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. Side question: Is it possible to change that OR by AND for comparisons? I know it is kind of unrelated, but it saves me another question here.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand, but I have edited by answer just in case. Perhaps another question would be best, there is no harm in that!

Comment: Sorry about that. It was about the operator itself. And yes, both of the answers work. Thanks a lot.